# What constitutes the determination of a normal blood glucose level?

Tags: metabolism, glucose

Several on-line resources (e.g. [MedlinePlus](http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/003482.htm)) suggest:

Normal range for non-diabetic people who are fasting should range between: 70 and 100 milligrams per deciliter (mg/dL)

Non-diabetic people who are not fasting should have a blood glucose level below 125 mg/dL

What I am interested in however, is the coverage interval of the population that was used to determine these 'normal' values.

Also are there differences based on age, sex or any other factors.

Answer (score 1):

Determining what is considered to be "normal" is quite challenging indeed. Both the ADA and the WHO look at upgrading diagnosis limits and both have a conservative approach, primarily due to the difficulties in conducting large scale studies and the anomalies between assumptions of plasma glucose distribution and what is probably actually present in populations. Digging through, I found a very good WHO document here:

http://www.who.int/diabetes/publications/Definition%20and%20diagnosis%20of%20diabetes_new.pdf

I am not going to regurgitate from this document, but I believe Issue 2 provides a detailed answer to your question detailing several determination methodologies.

As to your second question on age/sex variations, are you asking if the criteria are different? At least with reference to FPG, they don't appear to be so.

Comment: Summarising some of the bare bones of the document would actually improve your answer - admittedly the WHO website isn't likely to disappear overnight but files can be moved/renamed etc.

Comment: I am a layman in Biology. Recommendation 2 at the end of Issue 2 of the WHO document seems to suggest that the normal level should be assiciated with DM and CVD risk. This is hard for me to swallow. Would you also give us the link of ADA document if there is any? Some summaries will also be greatly appreciated. Thanks.